# jain sip registration: how to resend the registration request after calculating MD5 challenge

Tags: java, sip, jain-sip

I'm trying to authenticate with a SIP server using JAIN-SIP. I use the following code:

```
public class CoreEngine implements javax.sip.SipListener {
    //public localip=Inet4Address.getLocalHost().getHostAddress();
    SipFactory sipFactory = null;
    SipStack sipStack = null;
    Properties properties;
    HeaderFactory headerFactory;
    AddressFactory addressFactory;
    MessageFactory messageFactory; 
    SipProvider sipProvider;
    ListeningPoint lp;
    ContactHeader contactHeader;
    ClientTransaction inviteTid;

    public void init() throws Exception {
        sipFactory = SipFactory.getInstance();
        sipFactory.setPathName("gov.nist");
        properties = new Properties();
        properties.setProperty("javax.sip.STACK_NAME", "Sip_Test");
        // Create SipStack object
        sipStack = sipFactory.createSipStack(properties);
        headerFactory = sipFactory.createHeaderFactory();
        addressFactory = sipFactory.createAddressFactory();
        messageFactory = sipFactory.createMessageFactory();
        lp = sipStack.createListeningPoint("192.168.0.205", 5060, ListeningPoint.UDP);
        sipProvider = sipStack.createSipProvider(lp);
    }

    public void register() throws Exception {
        String fromName = "223344";
        String fromSipAddress = "173.194.117.84";
        String toSipAddress = "173.194.117.84";
        String toUser = "223344";
        SipURI fromAddress = addressFactory.createSipURI(fromName, fromSipAddress);
        System.out.println("sipuri fromaddress"+fromAddress);

        Address fromNameAddress = addressFactory.createAddress(fromAddress);
        FromHeader fromHeader = headerFactory.createFromHeader(fromNameAddress, null);
        SipURI toAddress = addressFactory.createSipURI(toUser, toSipAddress);
        Address toNameAddress = addressFactory.createAddress(toAddress);
        ToHeader toHeader = headerFactory.createToHeader(toNameAddress, null);

        URI requestURI = addressFactory.createURI("sip:" + "173.194.117.84");
        List<ViaHeader> viaHeaders = new ArrayList<ViaHeader>();
        String ipAddress = lp.getIPAddress();
        ViaHeader viaHeader = headerFactory.createViaHeader(ipAddress,
            lp.getPort(), lp.getTransport(), null);

        viaHeaders.add(viaHeader);

        CallIdHeader callIdHeader = sipProvider.getNewCallId();

        CSeqHeader cSeqHeader = headerFactory.createCSeqHeader(1L, Request.REGISTER);

        MaxForwardsHeader maxForwards = headerFactory.createMaxForwardsHeader(70);

        Request request = messageFactory.createRequest(requestURI,
            Request.REGISTER, callIdHeader, cSeqHeader, fromHeader,
            toHeader, viaHeaders, maxForwards);

        SipURI contactURI = addressFactory.createSipURI(fromName, "173.194.117.84");
        contactURI.setPort(sipProvider.getListeningPoint(lp.getTransport()).getPort());
        Address contactAddress = addressFactory.createAddress(contactURI);

        contactHeader = headerFactory.createContactHeader(contactAddress);
        request.addHeader(contactHeader);

        Header extensionHeader = headerFactory.createHeader("Expires", "120");
        request.addHeader(extensionHeader);
        System.out.println("request is"+ request);
        inviteTid = sipProvider.getNewClientTransaction(request);
        inviteTid.sendRequest();
    }

    public void processRequest(RequestEvent requestEvent) {
    }

    public void processResponse(ResponseEvent responseEvent) {
        System.out.println("Response received");
        System.out.println("response event"+ responseEvent.getResponse().getStatusCode());

        /*call function to calculate MD5 challege and to recreate the challenge request here */
    }

    public void processTimeout(TimeoutEvent timeoutEvent) {
    }

    public void processIOException(IOExceptionEvent exceptionEvent) {
    }

    public void processTransactionTerminated(TransactionTerminatedEvent transactionTerminatedEvent) {
    }

    public void processDialogTerminated(DialogTerminatedEvent dialogTerminatedEvent) {
    }
}
```

Now I have sent the request and I take the response by using `processResponse(ResponseEvent responseEvent)`. I also have a class to calculate the MD5 challenge and recreate the request packet including the authorization header which I call inside the `processResponse()` function.

How do I send this challenge request again to the server? And even if I send it, how do I process the reply back again as already `processResponse()` callback is being used?

Comment: Check the RFC for SIP digest authentication to use as reference. In a nutshell, you will send register, then the remote side will send you a challenge response. It may include extra parameters that must be interpreted. Then you send the same register on the same tags with your authorization header and from here its normal registration.

Comment: i have implemented SIP digest authentication in a different class.
I send the first register request and i take the response using processResponse() callback. After that i calculate the authorization header and recreate the request. now from here my problem begins.
1. how do i send the 2nd request to server
2. even if i send the 2nd request how do i process the reply

Comment: You should send the second register exactly like you send the first register. You may need to set the from tag FromHeader fromHeader = headerFactory.createFromHeader(fromNameAddress, tagHere); and repeat the same tag on the next register, increase the CSeq and that should be it. Still create a new transaction.